# Data is modified without my consent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I am using .NET MVC 5 and entity framework I have this model :

```
public class Division
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Manager")]
    public string ManagerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ManagerId")]
    public virtual AppUser Manager { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

So the Division Has a Manager.

When I keep the App running for a while, All related managers are removed without me doing any thing !
Only the relation is removed ( ManagerId = null ) instead of the Id, but they still there in the Users table.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**(Edit)**
Thank you Carl,
 
I put a Trigger on the table divisions, and I noticed that it get updated when I leave the app running **for a while** and then try to enter **any** page !

Comment: What actions are allowed on this entity? e.g. edit, delete? is the model posted your viewmodel as well as your database object? are you looking for a code reason for this happening, or foul play by a user?

Comment: Actions are allowed depending on the user role, so the Admin can edit and delete.

Comment: It's used in some views as the ViewModel.
The App is not published yet, so I am the only user, something strange is happening with the code think !

Comment: Is there a way to watch a specific table to know when it changes ? and what changes it ?

Comment: You could run  sql profiler - you need sql web or sql dev for this, i don't think it comes with express, or put a sql trigger on the table for update, and log as much info as you can. If you are running your app in debug, put a breakpoint on any code that commits to the db for this or related objects, giving you the chance to check the db before and after the commit.

Comment: If you are using it as a view model, and if manager is not populated after a post, its possible that it's being interpreted as you removing the manager object - this depends how your update code works - maybe post your controller and save method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved when I published without enabling ( running migration with the app first start up ).

I don't know the exact reason but I think when I leave the app running for a while and then enter any page, the Seed method was running again.